# JS - uploading file with web worker 405 error

Tags: javascript, file, web-worker, http-status-code-405

I am trying to upload multiple files using a web worker in javascript but am getting a 405 error.

This is my `index.html` file:

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<br /><br />
<output id="file_list"></output>
<br /><br />
<output id="messages"></output>

<script>
    var worker = new Worker('file_upload.js');
    worker.onmessage = function(e) {
        document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML += e.data+'<br />';
    }
    worker.onerror = werror;
    function werror(e) {
        console.log('ERROR: Line ', e.lineno, ' in ', e.filename, ': ', e.message);
    }
    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        evt.preventDefault();
        
        var files = evt.target.files;
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            file = files[i];
            document.getElementById('file_list').innerHTML += file.name+'<br />'+file.type+' - '+file.size+' bytes<br />';
            worker.postMessage(file);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```

this is the `file_upload.js` file

```
function upload(file){
    self.postMessage('uploading');
    
    fetch('/uploads', {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: file,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "text/plain"
        }
    })
    .then(response => {
        if(response.ok){
            return response;
        }else{
            throw Error('Server returned '+response.status+' - '+response.statusText);
        }
    })
    .then(response => {
        var response_text = response.text();
        self.postMessage('response '+response_text);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        self.postMessage(error);
    });
}

self.onmessage = function(e){
    self.postMessage('received');
    var file = e.data;
    upload(file);
}
```

The uploads folder has full permissions for read,write,execute (777)

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: 405 means the server doesn't understand the method used (here `PUT`). You'd have to check with your server what it expects. But given it seems you expect a response, a PUT request seems weird anyway.

Comment: What type of server are you using? Can you give us the server's code for the route?

Answer (score 0):

## Using PHP

Add a new file in root directory called `upload.php`:

```php
<?php
$myfile = fopen("/uploads/" . $_POST["name"], "w") or die("Unable to create file!");
$txt = $_POST["text"];
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Then edit your `file-upload.js`:

```js
function upload(file){
    let reader=new FileReader();
    reader.onload=()=>{
        self.postMessage('uploading');
        fetch('./upload.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: {name:file.name,text:reader.result}
        })
        .then(response => {
            if(response.ok){
                return response;
            }else{
                throw Error('Server returned '+response.status+' - '+response.statusText);
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
            var response_text = response.text();
            self.postMessage('response '+response_text);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            self.postMessage(error);
        });
    }
    reader.readAsText(file)
}
// ...
```

This should work!

---

## Using Node.js

If you have Node.js installed on your server, this is really easy. You don't even need a worker!

In `index.html` file:

```html
<!-- ... -->
<script type="module">
    var fs = require('node:fs/promises');
    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        evt.preventDefault();
        
        var files = evt.target.files;
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            file = files[i];
            document.getElementById('file_list').innerHTML += file.name+'<br />'+file.type+' - '+file.size+' bytes<br />';
            let reader=new FileReader();
            reader.onload=()=>{
                fs.writeFile('/uploads/'+file.name,reader.result)
                .then(()=>{
                    document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML += `File ${file.name} successfully uploaded!<br />`;
                })
                .catch(e=>{
                    console.error('ERROR:'+e);
                })
            }
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```

---

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The relevant bit of your code is that you are doing a `PUT` request to `/uploads`.

```js
    fetch('/uploads', {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: file,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "text/plain"
        }
    })
```

HTTP `405` status means "method not allowed".  Method in this case means `PUT` (could be `GET`, `POST`, `HEAD`, etc).

So the status code has the answer.  Whatever is listening to that HTTP request at `/uploads` does not accept HTTP request method `PUT`.

Your code is client-side (runs in browser).
You didn't say anything about what you were running server-side.

If you are just running a plain static webserver (nginx/apache), this is expected behaviour.  It would be weird if you ran a webserver and random people could just upload files freely to your HDD.  They could quickly fill up your disk and kill your server.

So the answer is that you need some service/API to listen at `/uploads` and accept a `PUT` request and handle the data.  This service/API should probably also require some authentication (is this a logged in user that is uploading?) and have some controls to prevent people from uploading files that are too large, etc.

Some of the other answers offer sample code that may help to handle the request on the server-side.  If you are following a tutorial, you may have missed a step relating to the server-side code to handle receiving the `PUT` file.